# Paging issue - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, asp.net-mvc

i am working with GridView in ASP.NET,
specifically PagerSettings and PagerStyle.
I have several questions.

Details:
look at the screenshot.
1) Page Index - it looks like Text field,where I input number of page-after pushing Enter 
-> it goes to that inputted page number.
2) How to make arrows bold?
3) How to position them (text field and arrows) in the middle (vertically)?

[image]

Comment: you need to look into HTML and css.

Comment: This is NOT a forum where you keep posting new questions/problems. And you must be kidding... Learn the basics first and you will easily solve this. This is not a babysit site...

Comment: And read this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: How is this issue related to asp.net MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at that links
[Custom paging with ASP NET GridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/410733/Custom-paging-with-ASP-NET-GridView)

[Some Tips and Tricks while Using ASP NET GridView Paging](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=244)

[Effective Paging with GridView Control in ASP NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125541/Effective-Paging-with-GridView-Control-in-ASP-NET)